# How can I add displaying image in my home page

Tags: python, django

Am creating a site where I want to post some information with image, in my admin page I can add image and it works fine. But when I come to the homepage it doesn't appear

Am using django and python. I know, the way I have used to call the image in the home template is not right, please help me how would I bring the image in my home page??

url

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
                path("", views.homepage,name="homepage"),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Home template

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="">button</a>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s12 m9" >
    {% for Doc in documents %}
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">

        <p>{{Doc.docs_name}}</p>
        <p>{{Doc.police_station}}</p>
        <p>{{Doc.docs_details}}</p>
        <img src = "{{Documents.docs_pic.url}}" width = "240">

    </div>
  </div>
 {% endfor %} 

</div> 

 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . models import Documents
from main.models import Documents


# Create your views here.

def homepage(request):
    return render(request=request,
                  template_name="main/home.html",
                  context={"documents":Documents.objects.all}

    )
```

Model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Documents(models.Model):
    docs_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    police_station = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    docs_details = models.TextField()
    docs_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="profileimages",blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.docs_name
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here:

First, in your `views.py` you're passing `Documents.objects.all` into the template context. You should be calling `Documents.objects.all()` as a function; note the `()` at the end

Second, in the template you reference `Documents.docs_pic.url`. You're in the forloop where `Doc` is the variable you've defined, so this should be `Doc.docs_pic.url`

Minor things as well: you should set `width="240px"` and the image tag should be closed, with `<img src="{{ Doc.docs_pic.url }}" style="width: 240px" />`

Comment: Thanks for reply, after following up above explanation picture icon is displayed but image didn't appear, something not right, am not sure was it, help please!